# PHP array_key_exists not working correctly

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents, array-key-exists

I have a php script that is supposed to assign virtual names to ip addresses.

```
<?php
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
$read = file_get_contents("vnames.json");
$json = json_decode($read);
var_dump($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
if(!array_key_exists($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $json)){
    $json[$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]] = generateRandomString();
    $read = json_encode($json);
    echo "This if statement is true!";
    file_put_contents("vnames.json", $read);
}
?>
```

Inside names.json, there are is only a pair of empty brackets.

So, I've figured out that `!array_key_exists($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $json)` is false. But, I'm sure that names.json does not contain my IP address.
I've assumed that this is is what's being evaluated:

```
<?php
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
$read = file_get_contents("vnames.json");//blank
$json = json_decode($read);//null
var_dump($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);//My ip
if(!array_key_exists($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $json)/*false*/){
    $json[$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]] = generateRandomString();
    $read = json_encode($json);
    echo "This if statement is true!";
    file_put_contents("vnames.json", $read);
}
?>
```

But in that case, file_get_contents is not working correctly.
Please help!

Comment: `var_dump($read);` what does it say?

Comment: There may be a permissions issue with accessing the file,

Comment: `array_key_exists` only checks the first dimension of the array, so you need to show the data structure of `$json` to see how deep it goes.

Comment: ```var_dump($read)``` Reads what it should read. ```string(2) "{}"```

Comment: the value of $json is a one dimensional associative array. It reads, {}.

Comment: Array_key_exist can only return true or false so if as you say (on your comment on my extended answer) it neither returns true or false that's very odd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_key_exists` is only for arrays, while the `$json` variable contains an object.

Either change `$json` to be an `array` or use `property_exists` for the object.

**Example to transform $json into an array**

```
$json = json_decode($read, true);
```

Comment: I tried both of those things. It didn't work. I'm pretty sure $json is an associative array, but I'm not sure. I tried var_dumping the ``` array_key_exists($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $json) ```, and It returned NULL, instead of a boolean.

Comment: I rewrote my entire code and it worked. Maybe I misspelled something.